# Access Update Query

Tags: c#, ms-access

This is my Update query which I have written in the code

```
string updateSql = "UPDATE RateCenters "+ "SET ProvinceName= @ProvinceName " + "WHERE ProvinceID=@ProvinceID";
```

I am getting the error as

**Invalid SQL statement; expected 'DELETE', 'INSERT', 'PROCEDURE', 'SELECT', or 'UPDATE'.**

kindly help me in this solution

regards,
Arjun

Comment: This is very little to go on. Can you provide more code please?

Comment: Is there anything between the "Update..." and + and "set.."

Comment: The string you have given us clearly starts with the word "UPDATE", so the contents of that string cannot be the cause of the error message you report ("... expected ... 'UPDATE'").  We therefore need more information.  How are you using the string `updateSql`?  What line of code causes the error?  Please post the entire method, or at least all of the code between the string declaration and the line where you get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need quotes `' '` across `@ProvinceName` and might be across `@ProvinceId`, depending on its type.